# Leer valor en especifico de un array

Tags: php, array

Buen dia, debo leer en PHP unos datos de un excel el cual puede contener datos  distintos en un dia a otro ya que se subira uno por ddia, asi que guardo todo en un array para luego hacer otra cosa que no viene al caso en este momento, este es el excel para este ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo excel lo leo y empaqueto en un array en javasctript y envio por ajax, aqui no importa eso pues todo eso funciona perfectamente, en el PHP lo recibo asi

```
$datos_excel = json_decode($_POST['array']);
$datos = print_r($datos_excel, true);
echo $datos;
```

ese echo me muestra

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [tercero] => 10986852 [vtas] =>
>   1076650 [nomb_terc_] => JAVIER FUENMAYOR ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHVGP.png) => stdClass Object (
>   [tercero] => 10686546 [vtas] => 1387300 [nomb_terc_] => CASTAÑEDA JOSE
>   ) ) Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [tercero] => 10986852 [vtas] =>
>   1076650 [nomb_terc_] => JAVIER FUENMAYOR ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHVGP.png) => stdClass Object (
>   [tercero] => 10686546 [vtas] => 1387300 [nomb_terc_] => CASTAÑEDA JOSE
>   ) )

Hasta aqui se que estoy recibiendo bien el array por ajax, lo que necesito es hacer un echo de un campo en especifico, intenté con

```
echo datos[0]['tercero'];
```

el cual se supone deberia mostrarme 10986852 que viene siendo el campo llamado 'tercero' de la posicion 0 pero no funcionó

alguna idea?

Comment: ¿pudieras colocar por favor que valor te regresa este echo `echo datos[0]['tercero'];`?

Comment: No he probado nada pero talvez porque te falta el `$` en el `echo datos[0]['tercero'];`

Comment: @Aprendiz haciendo echo $datos[0]['tercero']; me arroja "A" y segun veo es la A de la palabra Array, por que si hago eso mismo en posicion 3 me da la "r" y en la posicion 4  me da "y"

Comment: @Daniel haciendo echo $datos[0]['tercero']; me arroja "A" y segun veo es la A de la palabra Array, por que si hago eso mismo en posicion 3 me da la "r" y en la posicion 4  me da "y"

Comment: si hago echo $datos["tercero"]  como me dices igual obtengo A, como haria para obtener entonces, por ejemplo el valor 'tercero' de la primera linea que equivaldria a 10986852, en la segunda linea ese valor es distinto pues es 100686546, ese array puede tener 50 lineas solo que uso 2 para el ejemplo

Comment: Prueba asi `echo $datos[0]->tercero;` veo que lo que devuelve es un objeto

Comment: @Aprendiz haciendo echo $datos[0]->tercero; no obtengo respuesta alguna

Comment: prueba a convertir los datos en un array asociativo $mdatos = json_decode($_POST['array'],1); y haz un var_dump($mdatos) para ver el resultado, debería poder recorrerse como una array asociativo y no aparecer 'stdClass Object '.

Comment: El resultado de `echo $datos;` que muestras me confunde. El array tiene dos índices `0`, ¿por qué? Además, el valor `10986852` y otros, salen repetidos. ¿Será que los datos vienen mal organizados desde Ajax? La forma correcta de recibir los resultados sería como indica @Xerif en su respuesta. Y la lectura sería también como él indica (si los datos están bien organizados). No necesitas nada más, ni convertir a array el objeto JSON como sugieren otros.

Comment: @Carmen haciendo $datos_excel = json_decode($_POST['array']); y luego   var_dump($datos_excel); obtengo esto, https://snipboard.io/bJAtG8.jpg tuve que ponerlo en imagen por que aqui en comentarios no permite por la longitud de caracteres

Comment: @A.Cedano haciendo $datos_excel = json_decode($_POST['array']); y luego var_dump($datos_excel); obtengo esto, https://snipboard.io/bJAtG8.jpg tuve que ponerlo en imagen por que aqui en comentarios no permite por la longitud de caracteres

Comment: Para un futuro, puedes [edit] la pregunta y poner en ella **el texto** de la imagen que muestras (formateado si es posible para analizarlo mejor). La solución era lo que te decía @Xerif en su respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recordemos que `json_decode()` <sub>([ver documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php))</sub> admite un segundo parámetro que indica como queremos que devuelva los objetos json, si los queremos como array o como objeto. También es importante indicar que para acceder a la propiedad de un objeto se utiliza la sintaxis de flecha `->` en lugar de la de conchetes `[]` que es es para arrays. Expongamos un ejemplo:

```
<?php

$json = '[
    {
        "tercero": "10986852",
        "vtas": "1076650",
        "nomb_terc_": "JAVIER FUENMAYOR"
    },
    {
        "tercero": "10686546",
        "vtas": "1387300",
        "nomb_terc_": "CASTAÑEDA JOSE"      
    }
]';

// Como objetos
$datos = json_decode($json);
echo $datos[0]->nomb_terc_; // // JAVIER FUENMAYOR
print_r($datos);
// Resultado
/*
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tercero] => 10986852
            [vtas] => 1076650
            [nomb_terc_] => JAVIER FUENMAYOR
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tercero] => 10686546
            [vtas] => 1387300
            [nomb_terc_] => CASTAÑEDA JOSE
        )
)
*/

// Como array
$datos = json_decode($json, true);
echo $datos[0]["nomb_terc_"]; // JAVIER FUENMAYOR
print_r($datos);
// Resultado
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tercero] => 10986852
            [vtas] => 1076650
            [nomb_terc_] => JAVIER FUENMAYOR
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tercero] => 10686546
            [vtas] => 1387300
            [nomb_terc_] => CASTAÑEDA JOSE
        )
)
*/
```

Comment: Es correcto lo que dices, pero en la pregunta hay algo raro, **el `print_r` muestra dos índices `0`** en su array, por lo que me temo que los datos vienen mal organizados desde Ajax.

Comment: @Xerif Perfecto, tal cual lo que necesitaba, ya entiendo como esta organizado, ahora para recorrerlos ya que pueden ser 10, 20, 50 etc cantidad de registros, utilizaria un for verdad?

Comment: @gabriel para recorrerlos puedes utilizar un `for`, aún que siendo un array yo utilizaría un `foreach` por facilidad de uso y código.

Comment: @A. Cedano entiendo lo que dices y también me di cuenta al principio, pero realmente no es que devuelva mal los datos, es más bien que lo está imprimiendo 2 veces. Si los indentas es fácil apreciar que se han imprimido 2 veces o copiado 2 veces lo mismo en la pregunta.

Comment: Así es Xerif. Y me gustó tu respuesta porque es clara y porque además tratas el JSON como tal. Hasta ahora he visto que los usuarios de Stackoverflow en español tienen la costumbre de convertir los JSON a array sí o sí (aquí mismo hay dos ejemplos de ello), al parecer ignoran que un JSON se puede tratar como tal sin tener que convertirlo a array.

Comment: @Xerif lo estoy haciendo asi https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/300283/recorrer-datos-de-un-objeto-array-php pero no funciona, me ayudas porfa?

Answer (score 0):

> Cómo solución te propongo que hagas un **cast** del tipo de dato que tiene actualmente para pasarlo de `object` a `array` y de este modo al tener una matriz de datos puedas iterarlo por posición y clave

Imaginemos que tenemos una matriz de datos como la siguiente:

```
$datos = array(
    array("clave1" => "Hola", "clave2" => "Adiós"),
    array("clave1" => "Hi", "clave2" => "GoodBye")
);
```

Ahora casteamos esta matriz a un objeto del modo siguiente:

```
$valorObjeto = (object)$datos;

var_dump($valorObjeto);
```

Que me da en la pantalla un resultado como el siguiente:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["0"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["clave1"]=>
    string(4) "Hola"
    ["clave2"]=>
    string(6) "Adiós"
  }
  ["1"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["clave1"]=>
    string(2) "Hi"
    ["clave2"]=>
    string(7) "GoodBye"
  }
}
```

Que si revisamos tu pregunta es similar a lo que tu obtienes un objeto de la clase `stdClass`, entonces ahora casteamos de nuevo este objeto a un `vector` para poder obtener el valor de acuerdo con su clave y posición:

```
$valorVector = (array)$valorObjeto;
var_dump($valorVector);
```

Que me da en pantalla algo como esto:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["clave1"]=>
    string(4) "Hola"
    ["clave2"]=>
    string(6) "Adiós"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["clave1"]=>
    string(2) "Hi"
    ["clave2"]=>
    string(7) "GoodBye"
  }
}
```

> Ahora si revisas, tenemos una matriz de datos compuesta por 2 vectores internos, donde el primero ocupa la posición 0 y el segundo ocupa la posición 1; entonces si por ejemplo deseamos recuperar la `clave1` del vector en la posición **0** tendremos que hacer lo siguiente:

```
echo $valorVector[0]["clave1"];
```

Que me dará una impresión como la siguiente_:

> Hola

- Es importante notar la sintaxis requerida para obtener el valor deseado, del modo: `$variable[índiceQueOcupaElVectorDeseado]["ClaveALeer"]`.
- En caso de hacerlo distinto por ejemplo `echo $valorVector["clave1"][0];` te dará un error como este:

> Notice:  Undefined index: clave1 in [...][...] on line 20

El error anterior se da por que estas tratando de recuperar un vector en el índice **clave1** lo cual claramente no existe pues `clave1` es el nombre de la clave y **0** debería ser el índice a leer de la matriz de datos.

**Referencias**

- [`stdClass` y `casteo` de tipo de datos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting)

Comment: ¿Y por qué sugieres que se haga un casting a array, cuando se puede leer perfectamente como objeto? Además, la lectura como objeto es mucho más clara que la lectura como array. Y, no está probado, pero puede que sea más costoso convertir las cosas a lo que no son. O sea, si es un objeto, ¿por qué no dejarlo como objeto? ¿por qué se insiste en convertirlo a array? Te lo pregunto a ti y también a @Carmen (por [su comentario en la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/299797/leer-valor-en-especifico-de-un-array#comment547975_299797)). ¿Por qué hay que convertir a array?