# Recorrer un array de objetos con PHP

Tags: php, array, bucle-for, objeto

Buen día, tengo un array de objetos el cual me lee datos de un archivo excel, este puede tener X numero de filas, para el ejemplo uso estas dos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que el `for` no muestra nada, lo raro es que afuera del `for` cuando imprimo posiciones fijas como el 0, si me funciona.

Aquí el código PHP:

```php
<?php
  //array con las lineas de excel, en este caso solo 2
  $datos_excel = json_decode($_POST['array']);
  //examino la variable, mas abajo diré que arroja este var_dump
  var_dump($datos_excel);

  $conteo = count($datos_excel);
  //Imprimo conteo y efectivamnte me muestra que hay 2, es decir aqui voy bien
  echo "cantidad de datos: ".$conteo;

  //imprimo datos del primer registro el cual es posicion cero y muestra todo perfectamente
  echo "dato 'tercero posicion 0: ".$datos_excel[0]->tercero;
  echo "dato vtas posicion 0: ".$datos_excel[0]->vtas;
  echo "dato nomb_terc_ posicion 0: ".$datos_excel[0]->nomb_terc_;

  //aqui es donde quiero recorrerlo para luego hacer consultas mysqli con cada registro
  for ($i = 0; $i < $conteo; $i++)
  {
    //imprimo posicion para verificar que el for esta bien y efectivamente me muestra "posicion 0 posicion 1"
    echo " posicion: ".$i;
    //aqui es lo que no funciona, no muestra absolutamente nada
    echo $datos_excel[i]->tercero;
    echo $datos_excel[i]->vtas;
    echo $datos_excel[i]->nomb_terc_;
  }
?>
```

Aquí el var_dump del array:

> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["tercero"]=> int(10986852)
>   ["vtas"]=> int(1076650) ["nomb_terc_"]=> string(16) "JAVIER FUENMAYOR"
>   } [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2PJt.png)=> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["tercero"]=> int(10686546)
>   ["vtas"]=> int(1387300) ["nomb_terc_"]=> string(15) "CASTAÑEDA JOSE" }
>   }

Comment: Y cual es el problema o conflicto que tienes? dalo a conocer para poder ayudarte.

Comment: @Santiago en el for, ahi no muestra nada, lo raro es que afuera del for cuando imprimo posiciones fijas como el 0, si me funciona

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> El poblema es la variable i:

```
echo $datos_excel[i]->tercero;
echo $datos_excel[i]->vtas;
echo $datos_excel[i]->nomb_terc_;
```

> Solución: $i

```
echo $datos_excel[$i]->tercero;
echo $datos_excel[$i]->vtas;
echo $datos_excel[$i]->nomb_terc_;
```

Comment: O, se puede prescindir del `for` y de la variable `$i`, leyendo los elementos del array con un  `foreach`, tal y como indica @Xerif.

Answer (score 1):

Como te comenté en la otra pregunta puedes recorrer el array de objetos con un foreach, ejemplo:

```
<?php

$json = '[
    {
        "tercero": "10986852",
        "vtas": "1076650",
        "nomb_terc_": "JAVIER FUENMAYOR"
    },
    {
        "tercero": "10686546",
        "vtas": "1387300",
        "nomb_terc_": "CASTAÑEDA JOSE"      
    }
]';

// Como objetos
$datos = json_decode($json);

    foreach($datos as $fila) {
        echo $fila->tercero;
        echo $fila->vtas;
        echo $fila->nomb_terc_;
    }
```